# What is the minimum number of Legislators required to pass various Acts of Congress?

Tags: united-states, law, constitution, congress

1. Since the US Constitutional Quorum for most purposes is a majority of each house of Congress, can bills pass that house with a majority of the quorum or do they need a majority of the total seats of that house to pass?
2. Can a Presidential Veto be overridden with two thirds of the quorum, or is two-thirds of the total seats required?
3. What are the like requirements to propose a Constitutional Amendment?
4. What also are the requirements to change the procedural rules of the said House only?
5. Do Joint Resolutions have the same requirements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Theoretically a bill could pass both houses with only a single Senator and a single Representative present. The [Senate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_Rules_of_the_United_States_Senate) and the [House](http://congressionalresearch.com/98-988/document.php?study=VOTING%20AND%20QUORUM%20PROCEDURES%20IN%20THE%20HOUSE%20OF%20REPRESENTATIVES) both have rules that assume a quorum is present until someone challenges that fact, in which case a count is actually taken to determine if there is a quorum present. The [constitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quorum#United_States) defines a quorum as a simple majority, so the Senate requires 51 members present and the House of Representatives requires 218 members. The required number of members for a quorum is also adjusted should there be a vacant seat at that time.

The [U.S. vs. Ballin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_v._Ballin) established that a majority of the quorum is sufficient to pass a law. My reading of this [senate](http://www.senate.gov/CRSReports/crs-publish.cfm?pid=%270DP%2BP,C%3E%23P++%0A) pdf outlining veto override procedures indicates that a two thirds majority of the voting members is required, which could be two thirds of whatever quorum is present.

The rules appear to be the same for amendments in the [Senate](http://www.senate.gov/CRSReports/crs-publish.cfm?pid=%26%2a2%3C4RLO8%0A), in that two thirds of the quorum is valid. I couldn't find anything relating to the House but I would assume similar logic would be used.

Joint resolutions are work the [same as other bills](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_resolution) and are the vehicle for proposing amendments so they would also be passed by two thirds of present members, assuming a quorum.

Modifying the rules is a bit different, Both houses have rules in place that require a super-majority to change the rules, again a quorum being present. The [nuclear option](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_option) exists in the Senate, which allows the majority leader to effectively alter the rules with a majority vote even though the rules state a three fifths vote is required. This was done recently to prevent filibusters of appointments in the Senate, but otherwise had never actually been used due to other political concerns.

Comment: Just for reference, the [Palm Sunday Compromise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palm_Sunday_Compromise) passed the Senate 3-0.  As far as I'm aware, that was the smallest number of voting Senators ever.  It would be interesting to see if the single congressman in a [pro forma](http://politics.stackexchange.com/q/2603/2130) session could get away with passing solo legislation

Comment: @Bobson: The decapitation strike contingency scenarios depend on this working.